# Failed to fill orders

Tags: 0x

I used this code to fill an order, but it did not work. Can anyone help?

```
import { BigNumber, providerUtils } from '@0x/utils';
async function fill() {
  const utils = require("@0x/protocol-utils");
  const order = new utils.LimitOrder({
                  sender: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                  maker: "0x55c18a6d97e738d27b29ecd7018e04ef2da8ff0a",
                  taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                  takerTokenFeeAmount: "0",
                  makerAmount: "2600",
                  takerAmount: "2600",
                  makerToken: "0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d",
                  takerToken: "0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f",
                  salt: "0",
                  verifyingContract: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
                  feeRecipient: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                  expiry: "2014956256",
                  chainId: 3,
                  pool: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
              });
  const signature2 = await order.getSignatureWithKey(<my private key>,  utils.SignatureType.EIP712);
  const wrappers = require("@0x/contract-wrappers");
  var Web3 = require('web3');
  var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:8545/');
  const supportedProvider = providerUtils.standardizeOrThrow(web3.currentProvider)
  const exchange = new wrappers.IZeroExContract("0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff", supportedProvider);
  const amount = new BigNumber(1);
  const res = await exchange.fillLimitOrder(order, signature2, amount);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}
fill().catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Output:

```
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

So here you are filling an order that you created yourself. I guess this is only for testing purposes, as usually orders are taken from the open orderbook available on the 0x API https://0x.org/docs/api#get-srav4orderbook

In order to fill an existing order, you need to pay the 0x protocol fee (in ETH) and so the submitted transaction needs to contain a value field where the amount is equal to `gasPrice * feeMultiplier`

the feeMultiplier value can queried from the exchange contract by calling `getProtocolFeeMultiplier()`

Comment: Can you give me an example of code? I have never done it before.

Comment: yeah will take me sometime as there is no available tutorial I can share at the moment. sorry for that